# Exchanging $\min$ and expected value

Tags: probability, optimization

Consider the inequality

$\min \limits_{x} E_{\xi} \{Q(x,\xi)\} \ge E_{\xi} \{\min \limits_{x} Q(x,\xi)\},$

where $x$ is a vector of binaries, $\xi$ is a discrete random variable, and $Q(x,\xi)\ge 0$ for any $x$ and $\xi$. I think that above inequality holds for a simple problem I am working on, but I was wondering whether it holds in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$Q(y) \ge \min_x Q(x)\qquad\implies\qquad E(Q(y)) \ge E(\min_x Q(x)) \qquad\implies\qquad \min_y E(Q(y)) \ge E(\min_x Q(x))$$

Comment: No problem. If it helps, upvote it (and accept it when you can). If not, let me know here and I can clarify it.

Comment: Heh, my comment was the wrong way round! Accept it, and upvote when you can :) And thanks.

Comment: I've accepted it and will vote up as soon as I can (i.e. when I reach 15 reputation). Cheers!